# Is it smart to require_once wp-admin/includes/plugin.php when you need only one function from it

Tags: plugin-development

This question is loosely related to [Why some plugins are including wp-includes/plugin.php file?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/233562/why-some-plugins-are-including-wp-includes-plugin-php-file)

What I'm trying to figure out is, when is it smart to include this file, and when isn't it?

I'm building a plugin that'd need the `is_plugin_active()` function in the frontend (where it doesn't exist, because it's only loaded in `wp-admin`.

My gut says it's a waste (of memory or performance, maybe?) to include the entire `wp-admin/includes/plugin.php` just for the purpose of loading one function. So, IMO, a better idea would be to copy the `is_plugin_active()` function to my own plugin and run it from there.

Am I right about this? Or would you say: No, just `require_once()` the `plugin.php` file -- even if you only need one function from there? And if so, why?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Detect if another plugin you depend on is active?

Comment: I think including the file is right, unless it starts a cascade of including all the other admin code. Other plugins might be doing the same thing. If it’s only a few extra functions that won’t be significant extra resources.

Comment: @Rup I'm building a plugin which integrates a popular accounting software with a WordPress ecommerce plugin. During checkout, I'm also checking if certain 3rd party EU VAT plugins are active, so they can provide data about the used VAT rates or reverse charging.

Comment: Thanks. I noticed other addons were doing the same thing, so in this case it might even be a better idea to stick to that approach, even if it's not the best choice performance-wise -- about which I still not have found conclusive evidence.

Comment: Another option is you could check for the functions or classes you'd be calling, e.g. with class_exists or function_exists.

Comment: Yes, that's the approach I chose to go with (as you can see in the answer I posted below): use require_once(), but explicitly check for the functions you're planning to use first.

Comment: Oh, right, sorry I meant `if (class_exists('WC_EU_VAT_Compliance_Rates'))` etc. rather than for is_plugin_active to see if its plugin is loaded.

Comment: Right! Can't believe I didn't think of that. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, the answer isn't as straightforward as I initially hoped.

A quick test using `memory_get_usage()` on a local environment with only Twenty Sixteen enabled as the theme gives the following results:

```
Memory usage before requiring plugin.php: 8496336
Memory usage after requiring plugin.php: 8583912
```

So, loading `plugin.php` takes up 87.576 bytes, or roughly 85KB. If you only need one function from it, that's a lot.

Now, when I copy the function to my own code and measure memory usage again:

```
Memory usage before copied function: 8436128
Memory usage after copied function: 8436240
```

Now the difference is around 100 bytes. That's a significant difference!

From this we can conclude that in terms of effiency it would be smarter to copy the function from `plugin.php` into your own code. You might even argue that it's a shame that so many devs have chosen the easy route and simply imported wp-admin functionalities to the frontend.

But, this is exactly where the answer becomes vague.

There are A LOT of (very popular) plugins out there that're already loading `wp-admin/includes/plugin.php` in the frontend. In my local environment ~20%. So, you might say that at this point it's become a standard.

A few examples:

- AffiliateWP
- Avada (theme)
- Easy Digital Downloads
- Kirki-based themes
- WP Optimize

And, funny detail, core WordPress does it, too, in the WP_REST_Controller classes. You might even wonder why they haven't bothered moving it to a place where it's more widely available.

If you're building a publically available plugin (like I am), it's very likely your users are already using another plugin which is loading `plugin.php`. So, memory usage and/or performance won't take a hit if you simply do:

```
if (!function_exists('is_plugin_active')) {
    require_once(ABSPATH . '/wp-admin/includes/plugin.php';
}
```

I think it is good practice to check specifically for the functions you require, but other than that, at this point I'm saying: go for it.

Comment: It is accepted practice to simply include the file that has the function (though I would agree it's debatable as best practice). Another option is if `is_plugin_active()` does not exist, to define your own function. That would allow you to have reduced memory usage when possible. If the plugin is utilizing some sort of testing, writing tests to compare core `is_plugin_active()` with plugin's function would ensure detecting incompatibility.

Comment: I like that idea. I'll see if I can fit that into my code in a logical place. Thanks!